# Getting top 1 value for each month

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

this is the code:

```
select date_part('month',inspection.idate) as _month, inspector.iname, count(inspector.iname) as num
from inspector,inspection 
where inspection.idate>='2021/1/1' and inspector.iid = inspection.iid
group by inspector.iname, _month
order by _month
```

and this is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9eWG.png)

need to show top 1 count for each month, and for month number 6 there are 2 with same count, need to show both.

Comment: postgresql sql , it should be simple answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ranking Functions to resolve this. May be DenseRank or Rank.